# Server 500: This page isn’t working

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I am new web server and web hosting. I created a Fedora 28 web server to host my own website, and to learn the ins and outs of web serving. The apache is working, `http://<hostname>`. I even created a `phpinfo()` file, which works also; `http://<hostname>/info.php`. To test my directory access I added an `info.php` to that as well; `http://<hostname>/mywebdir/info.php`. However, in the same directory level I have a general `index.php` file, which is my controller for said project; `http://<hostname>/mywebdir/index.php` but it gets the "This page isn’t working  is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

```
security context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

I have edited the properties on this file to be executable. What could be blocking this file? Again I am just learning.

Comment: This sounds like an SELinux + webhosting issue, so I've flagged for migration to ServerFault. I'll search there to see if there's a similar question. In the meantime - where did you find that error message? (Though now that I think about it, that flag may be premature - I just assumed that was an error message. You should make sure a minimal index.php file also fails. If not, you probably just have an unlogged fatal error in your index php script.)

Answer (score -2):

Clearing all fatal errors will fix this issue. I forgot to install the pear package manager which threw fatal errors in my project.